# Handle multiple dropbox write requests in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to get JPEGs from NVR through FFMPEG within a loop for dates.

```
Porcelain.shell("ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 10000000 -i '#{stream_url}' -vframes 1 -y #{images_path}").out
spawn(fn ->
  File.exists?(images_path)
  |> upload_and_inject_image(config, images_path, upload_image_path, start_date, timezone)
end)
```

Then In upload and inject part, I am uploading jpegs to Dropbox as

```
  defp upload_image(status, image_path, upload_image_path) when status in [true, "true"] do
    client = ElixirDropbox.Client.new(System.get_env["DROP_BOX_TOKEN"])
    case ElixirDropbox.Files.upload(client, upload_image_path, image_path) do
      {{:status_code, _}, {:error, error}} -> Logger.debug "Error while uploading. Error: #{inspect error}"
      _ -> :noop
    end
  end
  defp upload_image(_status, _image_path, _upload_image_path), do: :noop
```

But file upload works fine if `Porcelain.shell("ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 10000000 -i '#{stream_url}' -vframes 1 -y #{images_path}").out`gets results a bit slow.

If that works fast, Dropbox API give errors as `too many operations at the same time`, I am using this library for [dropbox](https://github.com/sger/elixir_dropbox)

I tried to put sleep before Porcelain.shell command, but the results are the same. Is there any possibility to handle multiple concurrent operations at the same time to dropbox through elixir.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the limits of what Dropbox allows you to do. It's better to send multiple files in one `upload_session`.

Consider switching to `upload_session/start`, `upload_session/append` and [`upload_session/finish_batch`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload_session-finish_batch).

Comment: any example would be nice?

Answer (score 0):

So, after so many tries and failures I have found some workaround and I am just posting to get an opinion if there is a better solution than that is also possible.

after making dropbox client,

```
client = ElixirDropbox.Client.new(System.get_env["DROP_BOX_TOKEN"])
```

I am getting the file size first through this.

```
  defp get_file_size(image_path) do
    File.stat(image_path) |> stats()
  end

  defp stats({:ok, %File.Stat{size: size}}), do: {:ok, size}
  defp stats({:error, reason}), do: {:error, reason}
```

then I am starting a `upload_session` for each file separately such as

```
%{"session_id" => session_id} = ElixirDropbox.Files.UploadSession.start(client, true, image_path)
write_sessional_values(session_id, file_size, upload_image_path, path)
check_1000_chunk(path) |> length() |> commit_if_1000(client, path)
```

While starting `upload_session` if you are uploading a file in one request and not in chunk forms then your `close` headers should be `true`, it will tell api that no more chunks of the same file are going to be uploaded.

the other methods work like this

```
  defp write_sessional_values(session_id, file_size, upload_image_path, path) do
    File.write!("#{path}SESSION", "#{session_id} #{file_size} #{upload_image_path}\n", [:append])
  end

  defp check_1000_chunk(path) do
    File.read!("#{path}SESSION") |> String.split("\n", trim: true)
  end

  defp commit_if_1000(1000, client, path) do
    entries =
      path
      |> check_1000_chunk()
      |> Enum.map(fn entry ->
        [session_id, offset, upload_image_path] = String.split(entry, " ")
        %{"cursor" => %{"session_id" => session_id, "offset" => String.to_integer(offset)}, "commit" => %{"path" => upload_image_path}}
      end)
    ElixirDropbox.Files.UploadSession.finish_batch(client, entries)
    File.rm_rf!("#{path}SESSION")
  end
  defp commit_if_1000(_, _client, _path), do: :noop
```

I have to write down all sessions values to keep a record of them, in case of application stopped or started again to resume it from there.

The file size is important because you are going to pass it on when you will be finishing the batch.

with such values..

```
%{"cursor" => %{"session_id" => session_id, "offset" => String.to_integer(offset)}, "commit" => %{"path" => upload_image_path}}
```

So do you think there could be a better solution? for saving session values to a file? or anything in the code?